# Executing a ping from a remote server

Tags: vb.net

Using VS 2015 and VB.net.

I have a web application and I want to execute a ping from a remote server.  The server is running windows Server R2 2012.

The server has a router connected to it that goes to sleep periodically and at the moment we log in to the server and start a ping to the router to wake it up.  The web application will be accessed by various users and on a button click the ping would start.  The web application is hosted on our web server (not the remote server) and the ping must come from the remote server as the IP address of the router is local to the remote server and not visible to ping from anywhere else.

From my application I want to do this in code but I don't know where to start (been searching for a while).

I am not asking for the code I just want to know what I should be looking at.

Comment: your main problem is how to do a ping in vb?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9xkzk4s(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Fabrizio - no I can do that but its how to start it on a remote server

Comment: Create the code to do the ping and then create a scheduled task on server to call ping code on your desired schedule. You could probably do the same with a PowerShell script.

Comment: Is your remote server running IIS so you could make an ASPX page or ASMX to do the ping? Anything else installed on it (like SQL server, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

using a scheduled task as @Nkosi pointed in his comment is not a bad idea, but the most professional and stable way is to write a windows Service that will handle this task. a service is different than a process, its always runs on the background and NT User is not have to be logged in. you can setup timers to schedule the pinging inside the service application.  [Creating a Windows Service Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Funnily enough we do have a powershell script that is executed via a scheduled task to do this very thing but I wanted to be able to activate the ping from within my web application.

Comment: i did not suggest powershell script and not a scheduled task. Windows Service is an application that you develop with vb.net or C# using visual studio.